# Communication with underlying screen/route in flutter

Tags: android, navigation, flutter

I have a flutter app with two screens (routes). From the first one a user navigates to a second (via `Navigator.push`). On a second screen a user does some actions. And these actions should affect some widgets' states on a first screen. Of course while user is doing actions on the second screen the first one is not visible, but calling `Navigator.pop` should show the first screen already updated.

Is there any mechanism which allows communication between currently visible and underlying routes? (not sure, but are underlying routes' widgets/states even kept in memory after `Navigator.push` was called?)

I have some ideas, but they look like not a good practice.

- Do not use navigator and have a single stateful root widget which is used as a communication point between others. But this will require boilerplate reimplementation of `Navigator`
- Create a global variable for the same purpose. I'm not sure about how would it work with flutter widgets lifecycle because as a result, some widgets should depend on it and moreover wouldn't get updates if I don't implement any kind of `Listener` there (which would become invalid when some widgets are destroyet, i.e. it's also a lot of boilerplate).

I suspect there should be a better way of doing this.
Unfortunately I can't redesign the app to avoid using `Navigator`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Take a look at state management, something like streams. This library is a good example: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_stream_friends

Comment: see the returned value of `Navigator.push` method - also see `Navigator.pop` documentation